# Error: Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property dob?

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc

I am trying simple Spring-MVC application for form validations. I am facing an issue while taking date input from browser. The error is:

```
"Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property dob; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "2015-12-25"
```

This problem I am facing in Google Chrome browser only. In internet explorer and eclipse interface its working fine. I am using Chrome-40.0.2214.115m.

I am sharing part of my code here:

From Controller file:

```
...
@InitBinder     
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
     binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));   
}
...
```

From JSP file:

```
...
<tr>
<td><label for="dob">DOB</label></td>
<td><input type="date" name="dob" /></td>
<td><form:errors path="person1.dob" /></td>
</tr>
...
```

If there is problem with browser compatibility, then what is the solution for it? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Your `initBinder` method is expecting a date containing solidus (`/`) characters, and you've fed it one containing hyphens. Either fix the input, or change the expected format to match it. Suspect you'll have to do the latter, probably with some browser detection... or just try a different format if the first one fails.

Comment: @JonK Hi I am not giving input in the format (..-..-....). In error message only its showing like that

Comment: The error message is telling you what it tried to parse that failed - that hyphen-delimited date is what your `initBinder` method received

Comment: In chrome only its showing problem :(

Comment: If you are sure that the error shows in Chrome ONLY and NOT in other browsers while using IDENTICAL input that would indicate a bug in the OTHER browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input tag date format is always like **`YYYY-MM-DD`**. So change your format pattern while formatting to `SimpleDateFormat` with this `yyyy-MM-dd`.

So try this one

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thanks Harshal... Its working Now :) But I didn't understand.. While taking input (through calender interface) yts taking in d format ../../.... and while showing its in ..-..-.... format

Comment: @Madhusudan format with / is just for ui but actually value comes in - format as per tag standard